# how to disable system alert boxes in android?

Tags: android, sms

In the Android application, I am developing a one functionality that sends sms messages to given numbers automatically when the application is running. That function is working properly but after the messages is sent the cost for that messages prompts on a alert box.

Normally when I send a message that alert box prompts. But in my application I want to disable it because it disturbs to my application. How can I achieve that.

If you have any Idea then Please Guide me.
Thanks,
Reena

Comment: For small numbers of messages, what you are describing must be unique to your device or its manufacturer, as Android does not normally display a dialog with cost data. At some threshold (50? 100?), Android normally will display a dialog regarding the bulk SMS delivery.

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you explain In Detail for more Understanding?

Comment: That's a lot of detail already, I guess. B-)

Comment: that happens for prepaid connections.

Comment: @GaurawYadav Please Can you explain in detail?

Comment: don't you think it's bad that your user wouldn't know that money is being deducted?

Comment: @GaurawYadav yes i know but its requirement so please tell me

Answer (score 3):

These pop-ups are flash messages that are generated by SIMCARD network provider. There is nothing you can do about it from your app end to put an end to them. But, you can stop it by disabling `SIMCARD Services` settings.

For disabling flash message you may check the link:

http://www.imobileandroid.com/disable-pop-flash-message-vodafone-android/

It has a process mentioned. So if you can have your all customers devices with you, sure you can stop it, otherwise NO.

**Authors Note :** *Better stop worrying about it ;)*